# Navigate to external link if last page or post in a category

Tags: plugin-development, navigation, links, previous-post-link

I'm working on a project that ties in an old legacy site with a replacement Wordpress site.

Is there a way I can add a link to a the post navigation to an external link when a user reached the last post in a category?

Comment: please modify the question, it's hard what you mean by `link to a the post navigation to an external link` . Use examples what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's not clear exactly what you need it's hard to give you the best solution.

However ...
You should be able to use get_next_posts_link() in your loop template. Or get_previous_posts_link() if that's what you want.

If that returns null you can then echo a link to whereever you want in your template.

```
if(!get_next_posts_link()) {
    echo '<a href="http://linktosomewhere.com">Continue to somewhere else</a>';
}
```

Won't work in custom loops though. Then you have to reference max_num_pages.

```
if(!get_next_posts_link( 'whatever', $your_query->max_num_pages )) {  }
```